# Shrink a .sparseimage

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility, hdiutil, sparseimage

I have a `.sparseimage` that occupies 90GB of space on my hard drive despite only having 30GB of files in it. How can I reclaim the empty space used by the `.sparseimage` and compact the file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some cursory searching, I found a forum post pointing to `hdiutil`'s `compact` verb. From the `man` page:

> **compact** image
>
> scans the bands of a sparse (SPARSE or
>   SPARSEBUNDLE) disk image containing an
>   HFS filesystem, removing those parts
>   of the image which are no longer being
>   used by the filesystem.  Depending on
>   the location of files in the hosted
>   filesystem, compact may or may not
>   shrink the image.  For SPARSEBUNDLE
>   images, completely unused band files
>   are simply removed.

I ran `hdiutil compact drive.sparseimage` and it successfully reclaimed almost 98% of the space.

(I guess it's one of those days... I should really learn to Google stuff first).

*Edit:* I tested `compact` on a 1GB `sparseimage` with just a few text files, and it ran quite quickly, but my Mac is taking quite a while to compact the 90GB image. Be prepared to wait.

Comment: Prepare for hours of fun watching that second progress indicator creep to the right edge of the Terminal.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my answer a bit. I tested it on a smaller `sparseimage` and it ran quite quickly, but it's taking quite a while on the large image. It's times like these I'm thankful I upgraded to a 7200RPM hard drive!

Comment: It's related to how much reorganizing that task needs to do. It's usually pretty fast if you dump some files into the `sparseimage`, pull them back out, and them compact, since the system can just throw away those bytes.

Comment: If you get an error "hdiutil: compact failed – Function not implemented": http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132147/hdiutil-compact-failed-function-not-implemented

Answer (score 8):

1. Double click the `.sparseimage` file to open it
2. Empty the trash
3. Eject the `.sparseimage` drive
4. Enter this into Terminal: `hdiutil compact path-to-file.sparseimage`

Comment: I like the addition of "Empty the trash" I think that is a step that is easy to overlook.