# Is it safe to cancel hdiutil compact?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, hdiutil, sparseimage

A [sparse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_image) is a type of disk image file used on Mac OS X that grows in size as the user adds data to the image, taking up only as much disk space as stored in it (quoth Wikipedia). If a sparse image takes up more space than the data it contains, that space can be reclaimed with the Terminal command `hdiutil compact path/to/file.sparseimage`, as explained in answer to [Shrink a .sparseimage](https://superuser.com/questions/275148/shrink-a-sparseimage).

Now my question: Is it safe to abort (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) a compacting operation, or could that cause damage to the image?